# Android: Register Receiver in Library

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have a library that includes an activity named as `BaseActivity` and a receiver named as `BaseRegister`.

`BaseRegister` extends `BroadcastReceiver` and its actions are `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` and it looks like:

```
public class BaseRegister extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if {
            Log.d("onReceive", "Got it"); // Works
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("some"));
        else {
            Log.d("onReceive", "Nope"); // Works
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("stuff"));
        }
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest` is fine too, according to `Log`. Here is how `BaseActivity` looks like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerReceiver(applicationControl, new IntentFilter("some"));
        registerReceiver(applicationControl, new IntentFilter("stuff"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver applicationControl = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.equals(new Intent("some"))) {
                some();
            } else if (intent.equals(new Intent("stuff"))) {
                stuff();
            }
        }
    };

    public void some() { /** logging etc **/ }
    public void stuff() { /** logging etc **/ }


}
```

In project, I've already added this project as a library, no problem. And created an Activity which extends `BaseActivity`. When `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` as an action, `BaseRegister` triggered by Android, but there is no call for Activity. Here is how my project looks:

```
public class AnyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

    @Override
    public void some() {
        super.some();
        Log.d("abc", "abc"); // not working
    }


    @Override
    public void stuff() {
        super.stuff(); 
        Log.d("abc", "abc"); //not working
    }

}
```

What is wrong? Is my approach improper or does any error exist? Any help would be great.

Comment: Is your `AnyActivity` active when you get that broadcast?

Comment: Nope. That's actually my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseActivity will invoke the methods "closest" in scope, this is normal core Java behavior and not unique to Android.  If you really want to keep the BroadcastReceiver in a base class and signal children then you will need something like a custom listener, i.e. the children register at runtime and when events arrive they will be notified.

Also, is is considered good practice to disable a broadcast receiver when the Activity is not top of stack, so you might wish to use registerReceiver()/unregisterReceiver() within onResume()/onPause()

Good luck.

Comment: You're right, if I register in the children, that works. So there is no way to register in base class. What about custom listener? Can you give any example Q&A example.

Comment: You can keep the BroadcastReceiver in the base class, the real problem is you cannot currently signal the children.  How about adding a register(Activity me) method to your base?  Within the method keep an ArrayList of child Activity which you will invoke as events arrive.  FWIW, there isn't any real harm in each Activity having their own BroadcastReceiver apart from the duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not register the BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifest?  Like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BaseRegister">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="some" />
            <action android:name="stuff" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```